# How to determine variable is String or not in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In WebviewController - userContentController method, the "didReceive message" parameter has a "body" property:

message.body

"body" is type of "Any",I must force cast it to String or Int.

But if "body" is Int, and I cast it to String, the app will crash,

So I have to determine the type of "body",and what can I do?

Comment: How do you cast it? `if let string = body as? String {...} else if let value = body as? Int {...} else {...}` should work

Comment: What's the method? is that means `func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController,
                         didReceive message: WKScriptMessage)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to, and should not, use force casting.
Joakim's answer of using "Optional Binding" and a series of if statements works:

```
if let string = body as? String { 
  // Do something with 'string'
} else if let value = body as? Int {
  // Do something with 'value' 
} else {
  // Handle unknown types
}
```

But if you're going to handle more than 2 cases I prefer to use a switch statement:

```
let array: [Any] = [2, "fish", Double.pi, 7, "eggplant", CGFloat.squareRoot(2.0)()]

let body = array.randomElement()

switch body {
case let anInt as Int:
    print("'\(anInt)' is an int")
case let aString as String:
    print("'\(aString)' is a String")
case let aDouble as Double:
    print("'\(aDouble)' is a Double")
case let aCGFloat as CGFloat:
    print("'\(aCGFloat)' is a CGFloat:")
default:
    print("\(body) is an unknown type")
}
```